# Sql query related to left inner join or right inner join?

Tags: sql, join

Could you write an SQL query that has a table `A` and table `B` where table `A` has an `ID` and table `B` refers to table `A`'s ID as `A_ID` and get all the rows that are in table `A` and the rows that match in table `B` (even if there is no match in table `B`)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the difference between INNER JOIN, LEFT JOIN, RIGHT JOIN and FULL JOIN?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5706437/whats-the-difference-between-inner-join-left-join-right-join-and-full-join)

Answer (score 1):

This can easily be done with a `left join`:

```
SELECT    a.id, b.a_id
FROM      a
LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id
```

Comment: Thanks Mureinik I realy appreciate your instant response once again Thanks...... :)